# HTTP redirect from MS Access

Tags: http, ms-access, redirect, cookies

In my web application, there's a link sending a redirect (302 to another GET request) together with some cookies. It works fine, except when used from MS Access by a guy I remotely work with. I know close to nothing about what and how he does, I only know that he uses `Application.FollowHyperlink`.

The link from Access should be opened in a browser, but after the redirect, there seem to be no cookies there. When used normally, there's no problem. Can it be like that Access handles the link itself and sends the redirected URL to the browser?

Maybe a stupid question, but I have no idea about Access (never ever seen it) and I'm sitting only on the server side. There's nothing interesting in the server logs...

Comment: So, he's the only 'user' this happens with? I'm a little confused. Are you performing this elsewhere and it is working?

Comment: @OverMind The users are supposed to use a web browser, no MS Access. I can't perform it elsewhere as I have no MS Access, but it's clear in the meantime. Actually, everything can be found in the answer linked, however, it took me quite some time, so I keep my Q&A here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was MS doing some complicated things like [here](https://superuser.com/a/445431/64359) instead of simply opening an URL in a browser. Access accesses the page, sees the new URL, and gets and eats all cookies. While digesting the cookies, it points the browser to the new URL. The browser has no cookies and no access to anything.

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/838028) summarizes it nicely:

> This problem occurs because of missing session cookies for the Web server. This problem is specific to certain Web-server designs that depend on cookie information instead of authentication information or that depend on cookie information plus authentication information.

To me it sounds like "works with MS only", though I'm not exactly sure what "authentication" they mean.